# Get-ADOrganizationalUnit returns blank value

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-module

Just looking for a count of OUs nested within other OUs. I am using the 'OneLevel' scope which should give me any OU objects directly under the parent, but not the parent itself.

Example (pulling entire subtree including parent):

```
PS C:\> $OUCountSubtree = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase 'OU=MyParentOU,DC=USA,DC=hello,DC=there'
PS C:\> $OUCountSubtree.Name
PS C:\> MySubOU
PS C:\> MyParentOU
PS C:\> $OUCountSubtree.Count
PS C:\> 2
```

So that works great. However, when I attempt to return the count of discovered objects, or I attempt any integer operations with the resulting numbers, it errors out if the count is 1. When it's 0 or 2+, it works. Also when I display the full results (instead of just the count), everything looks fine.

Example (pulling only child OUs):

```
PS C:\> $OUCountOneLevel = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchScope OneLevel -SearchBase 'OU=MyParentOU,DC=USA,DC=hello,DC=there'
PS C:\> $OUCountOneLevel.Name
PS C:\> MySubOU
PS C:\> $OUCountOneLevel.Count
PS C:\>
```

Sanity checks

```
PS C:\> $OUCountOneLevel

City                     :
Count                    : {}
Country                  :
DistinguishedName        : OU=MySubOU,OU=MyParentOU,DC=USA,DC=hello,DC=there
LinkedGroupPolicyObjects : {}
ManagedBy                :
Name                     : MySubOU
ObjectClass              : organizationalUnit
ObjectGUID               : [some guid]
PostalCode               :
State                    :
StreetAddress            :
```

So there is a single OU returned. And yet...

```
PS C:\> $OUCountOneLevel.Count -eq 0
PS C:\> False
PS C:\> $OUCountOneLevel.Count -eq $null
PS C:\> False
PS C:\> $OUCountOneLevel.Count -eq ''
PS C:\> False
PS C:\> 5 + $OUCountOneLevel.Count
PS C:\> Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
```

I've been doing this kind of thing for years and I don't recall ever seeing seen this behavior before. Why would this not return an integer of 1? I have not declared an array or anything beyond a simple query to AD.

Comment: Try forcing an array: `@(Get-...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative answer: Use Powershell Cmdlets not properties of objects.

Powershell includes the `Measure-Object` Cmdlet which is great when you do not know if a result can be `$null`, an array or a single object. On the negative part - its Powershell - so it will be longer lines of code. Probably more expensive in terms of resources as well.

```
$OUCountOneLevel | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
```

This "problem" is however not limited to AD Cmdlets, it is inherit in all operations. If the result of the last element in a pipeline is no objects, the result is `$null`. If it is a single object, it will be a single object. If it is multiple objects, it will be an array.

However - this also happens when you try to add something to something you believe is a list. The following works fine given that there is more than one user named johndoe:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter 'name -like "johndoe"'
$users += $someotherobject
```

But if its a single user - you have to force the array somehow. I do this, which probably results in the same as Gabriel Luci's answer.

```
$users = @()
$users += Get-ADUser -Filter 'name -like "johndoe"'
$users += $someotherobject
```

Comment: Couldn't I avoid ever having this issue by prefacing the name of any variable that I expect to be an array with the [array] identifier? Not sure how that would handle $null though.

Comment: Prefacing a variable with type in Powershell actually does something weird if you do not know about it: It locks the data type of that variable. [String[]]$MyObject forces $MyObject to always be a String Array. So even if you do $MyObject = 5, $MyObject is still an array. Can probably be used/abused. It seems that it does not work for $null though ([Object[]]$p = $null) will cause $p to be undefined.

Comment: Some note on my comment - it seem that left declaration does not lock it to an array, since it will be $null when set to $null. However, everything except that is $null wil be tried to be converted back to get type you declared. Explore the variable name with Get-Variable to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

TheIncorrigible1 has the right idea in the comments.

Many of the AD cmdlets return an array if there is more than one result but return the object itself if there is only one. If you want to consistently get an array, then you can force it using `@(...)`:

```
$OUCountSubtree = @(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase 'OU=MyParentOU,DC=USA,DC=hello,DC=there')
```

Read more about the "array sub-expression operator" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-6#the-array-sub-expression-operator